# Solve random native crash on LibGDX game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Some of the users of an android game in which I'm working were experimenting a critical crash that sometimes hang their mobiles. This bug only happens when the game ends (when the player die and is outside the viewport). As this is a pretty serious bug, I refactored the code and now the problem is gone for some users, but not all.

The report that I receive in Google Play is always something similar to this:

```
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 30442, tid: 30464, name: Thread-458 >>> com.mygdxgame.android <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 78c0b008
r0 78c0b008 r1 42bd8500 r2 00000188 r3 00000008
r4 753669c0 r5 42bd84f8 r6 b0800005 r7 78c0b008
r8 7547db10 r9 7537fd8c sl 75366a48 fp 7547db24
ip 00000000 sp 7547dae8 lr 75347c54 pc 4009e01a cpsr 60010030
d0 4458c000445b4000 d1 7e37e43c3c000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 408b780000000000 d5 bf800000c0000000
d6 0000000000000000 d7 3f80000000000000
d8 408b180000000000 d9 408b1c0000000363
d10 0000000000000000 d11 3f80000000000000
d12 00000000000000ff d13 80000000bca3d70a
d14 bf80000080000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 409f255618c5b67c d17 414e508260000000
d18 3fe45f306dc9c883 d19 4337fffffffffff7
d20 bfdffffffd0c5e81 d21 3fa55553e1053a42
d22 3fefb9659d96e85e d23 3f33872815df26e1
d24 3ef99342e0ee5069 d25 3ed592dfbf0a142d
d26 bfc0c4d52f39a3ad d27 bf62943a05b10df4
d28 3f33872815df26e1 d29 3ec6cd878c3b46a7
d30 bea6acf61c48ffe8 d31 c00921fb54442d18
scr 20000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 0002201a /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+69)
#01 pc 00037c50 /data/app-lib/com.mygdxgame.android-1/libgdx.so     (Java_com_badlogic_gdx_utils_BufferUtils_copyJni___3FLjava_nio_Buffer_2II+88)
#02 pc 0001dbcc /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#03 pc 0004e123 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*,     Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#04 pc 00026fe0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 0002dfa0 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#06 pc 0002b638 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*,     JValue*)+184)
#07 pc 00060581 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*,     bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#08 pc 000605a5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*,     JValue*, ...)+20)
#09 pc 0005528b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 0000d170 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#11 pc 0000d308 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
4009dff8 f811cb01 f800eb01 f800cb01 ea5feb01 
<lines ommited>

code around lr:
75347c34 e12fff3c e59d101c e59d2018 e1a02102
<lines ommited>
```

I don't get any info with this stack trace so I don't know how to fix the bug.

After reading some post of people with a similar error (signal 11), I'm pretty sure that the error is related to Box2D or the batch that I use.

Here is part of the code involved in the bug.

**GameScreen**

```
public GameScreen(MyGdxGame game) {
    super(game);

    worldNotifier = new WorldNotifier();

    worldController = new WorldController(game, worldNotifier);
    worldInputProcessor = new WorldInputProcessor(worldNotifier);

    worldNotifier.addListener(worldController);
    worldNotifier.addListener(achievementsUnlocker);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    if (!paused) {

        /* Update game world */
        worldController.update(delta);
    }

    /* Clear screen */
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /* Render game world */
    worldRenderer.render();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    worldRenderer.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    GamePreferences.getInstance().load();

    worldRenderer = new WorldRenderer(worldController);

    /* Initialize controller and renderer */
    worldController.init();
    worldRenderer.init();

    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(worldInputProcessor));
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    worldRenderer.dispose();

    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(false);
}
```

**WorldController**

```
public WorldController(MyGdxGame, WorldNotifier worldNotifier) {
    this.game = game;
    this.worldNotifier = worldNotifier;

    rockSpawner = new RockSpawner(this);
    cameraHelper = new CameraHelper();
    cameraHelper.setAxisLocked(false, true);
}

private void showScore() {
    game.scoreScreen.setScore(withstoodTime);
    game.setScreen(game.scoreScreen);
}

public void init() {
    if (world != null) {
        world.dispose();
    }

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);

    /* Instantiate game objects */
    <code omited>

    /* Set up controllers, listeners and... your know, all the stuff needed */
    buoyancyController = new BuoyancyController(world, water.sensor);
    buoyancyController.linearDrag = Constants.WATER_DRAG_FORCE;

    world.setContactListener(new WorldContactProcessor(this, worldNotifier));

    rockSpawner.init();
    cameraHelper.setTarget(pirate);

    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();
}

public void update(float delta) {

    /* Update withstood time */
    withstoodTime = TimeUtils.millis() - startTime;

    /* Update game objects */
    <code omited>

    rockSpawner.update(delta);

    buoyancyController.step();
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

    cameraHelper.udpate(delta);
}

@Override
public void onPlayerFalling() {
    player.die();
}

@Override
public void onPlayerOutsideViewport() {
    game.googlePlayServicesResolver.submitScore((int) withstoodTime);

    showScore();
}
```

**ScoreScreen**

```
public ScoreScreen(MyGdxGamegame) {
    super(game);

    font = new BitmapFont();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    /* Clear screen */
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    String scoreText = "Your score is: " + score;
    BitmapFont.TextBounds textBounds = font.getBounds(scoreText);
    font.draw(batch, scoreText, (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - textBounds.width) / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 20);
    batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);
    }
}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    game.googlePlayServicesResolver.showAds(true);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    batch.dispose();

    game.googlePlayServicesResolver.showAds(false);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    font.dispose();
}

public void setScore(long score) {
    this.score = score;
}
```

So, the error happens sometime between onPlayerOutsideViewport call (this comes 1 or 2 seconds after onPlayerFalling) and first render of ScoreScreen. The callback (onPlayerOutsideViewport ) is called by a Box2D ContactListener who notify the event using another class, WorldNotifier who send a notification to all WorldListeners.

I'm omitting a lot of code but I could add it if you need it. Anything to resolve this annoying bug.

Comment: You are calling a native method which then calls memcpy with pointers obtained from the passed objects and an offset and length passed as raw numbers.  One of those is apparently invalid.  You can instrument either the cpp code or the java code to try to figure it out, or you can try to seek resolution through the author of this framework.

Comment: One way to corrupt one of the native buffers that LibGDX uses is to `dispose` of them too soon.  You might try adding some checks that objects you dispose of are not actively in use and do not get reused.